# All possible combinations of elements from sets of different sizes

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I am creating a tool for my private use, but I reached a complex combination issue.

I have dict of 7 sub-dicts of similar format:

```
{"D1": {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C":6},
 "D2": {"D": 4},
 "D3": {"E": 8, "F": 12, "G": 2}.
 "D4": {"H": 9, "I": 3}.
 "D5": {"J": 2},
 "D6": {"K": 8, "L": 1},
 "D7": {"M": 2}}
```

What I need is to generate all possible dicts that will combine 1 element from each dict in such format:

```
[{"D1": "A", "D2": "D", "D3": "E", "D4": "H", "D5": "J", "D6": "K", "D7": "M"},
 {"D1": "A", "D2": "D", "D3": "F", "D4": "I", "D5": "J", "D6": "L", "D7": "M"},
 and all other possible combinations]
```

The output should be a list of all possible unique combinations along the elements from all DX dicts.
I am probably able to make a solution of this problem using some very complicated, ugly looking, nested for loops with plenty of ifs, but there is probably a very nice way to make it in itertools or something similar.

Any help with doing that task efficiently?
This task needs to be repeated on big set of such dicts, so the performance is the key.
Thanks!

Comment: the tricky (and probably unavoidably ugly) bit is getting `"D1"` out of the `globals`; the rest is easy `itertools` work

Comment: Actually there is a list of dicts looking like that: [{D1: ..., D2: ... D3: ...}, {D11: ..., D22: ..., ...}, ...].

Comment: and you only want these specific ones that stand out how exactly? due to their name?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess the question was not stated clearly enough. Let me rework it :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks a bit complicated, but a fairly simple solution:

```
import itertools

D = [D1, D2, D3, D4, ...]

dicts = [
    dict(zip([f'D{i+1}' for i in range(len(D))], iter)) 
    for iter in itertools.product(*[list(d.keys()) for d in D])
]

dict_1 = dicts[0]
dict_2 = dicts[1]
...
```

```
dicts = [
    {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H'},
    {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I'},
    {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H'},
    {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I'},
    ...
]
```

#### How it works:

Generate all combinations of keys

```
itertools.product(*[list(d.keys()) for d in D])
```

Combine the combinations with the appropriate dict name

```
zip([f'D{i+1}' for i in range(len(D))], iter))
```

Combining the two parts and converting each of them to a dictionary

```
[
    dict(zip([f'D{i+1}' for i in range(len(D))], iter)) 
    for iter in itertools.product(*[list(d.keys()) for d in D])
]
```

Comment: Perfect! I can work with that! :) The itertools issue was too hard for me. I need to learn itertools better!

Comment: Good to hear. I've realised I didn't add D in the solution, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the Cartesian product of your dictionaries.
Fortunately, `itertools` define a `product` function that does exactly that.

When used as an iterable, a `dict` will yield its keys, so `product(D1, D2, ...)` will directly yield tuples of keys such as `('A', 'D', 'F', ...)`.

You'll need a bit of tweaking to get exactly the output you want:

```
from pprint import pprint
import itertools

dicts = [
    {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C":6},
    {"D": 4},
    {"E": 8, "F": 12, "G": 2},
    {"H": 9, "I": 3}
]

r = [
    {f"D{i}": key for i, key in enumerate(x, 1)}
    for x in itertools.product(*dicts)
]
pprint(r)
```

Output:

```
[{'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I'}]
```

Comment: Amazing guys! Thank you so much!

Comment: @StarTrekFan You're welcome! Take some time to learn `itertools` more in depth, and also have a look at the amazing [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) :)

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is your friend:

```
from itertools import product

d = {"D1": {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C":6}, 
     "D2": {"D": 4},  
     "D3": {"E": 8, "F": 12, "G": 2}, 
     "D4": {"H": 9, "I": 3}, 
     "D5": {"J": 2}, 
     "D6": {"K": 8, "L": 1}, 
     "D7": {"M": 2}}

res = []
for c in product(*(v.keys() for _, v in d.items())):
  res.append(dict(zip(d.keys(), c)))
```

the list-comprehension version of which would be:

```
res = [dict(zip(d.keys(), c)) for c in product(*(v.keys() for _, v in d.items()))]
```

which produces:

```
[{'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'A', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'B', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'E', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'F', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'H', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'K', 'D7': 'M'},
 {'D1': 'C', 'D2': 'D', 'D3': 'G', 'D4': 'I', 'D5': 'J', 'D6': 'L', 'D7': 'M'}]
```

---

**Pros and Cons**

(+) Unlike the other answers, this one does not rely on the naming of the subdicts following the `D<i>` schema; they can be called whatever.

(-) the order of the dict has to be preserved so you need Python 3.5+